# How to kill the live-server from windows machine using sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-live-server

So I am building a react app using npm, the problem is whenever I start the live-server to update the website automatically for any changes I make in the code, the terminal just freezes and it does not let me type anything. I am opening the terminal on windows 10 on the editor sublime text itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stop running the server (meaning your app will no longer be available on localhost), you should be able to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>c</kbd> to stop any running processes in the current terminal tab.

---

When you’re running a server/process in terminal, you’ll need to open a separate tab/window to do anything else.

You should look at the documentation for the terminal package you’re using in Sublime to find out how to open a new tab, or just use the built-in terminal which definitely supports multiple tabs/windows.

Comment: thank you so much ctr + c worked to kill the process

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but are u using live-server package? If you are u can specify **wait** parameter before starting server something like this

```
var liveServer=require("live-server");
var params={          
 wait= 1000   //thats in ms milliseconds
};
liveServer.start(params);
```

Taken from official [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server). If u wana kill it then u have to do it manually like JBallin said

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But above answer solved the problem, it was actually ctr + c